# Working with MySQL date + time in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, datetime

Is there any Java Library or class that makes it easy to work with MySQL datetime fields?

For example, something that will take a string in MySQL Date format, and return a Java date object?

If not, is it better to store dates/times in a format other than MySQL datetime, to make it easier to work with them in Java?

Comment: Have you checked `DateFormat` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion/4216767#4216767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the SimpleDateFormat class. You will need to work out how the date is stored in MySQL and accordingly use the pattern.

Please read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for details.